# CLR / High memory consumption after switching from 32-bit process to 64-bit process

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, clr

I have a backend application (windows service) built on top of .NET Framework 4.5 (C#). The application runs on  Windows Server 2008 R2 server, with 64GB of memory.

Due to dependencies I had, I used to compile and run this application as a 32-bit process (compile it as x86) and use /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag to let the application use more than 2GB memory in the user space. Using this configuration, the average memory consumption (according to the "memory (private working set)" column in the task manager) was about 300-400MB.

The reason I needed the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag, and the reason i changed it to 64-bit, is that although 300-400MB is the **average**, once in a while this app doing stuff that involves loading a lot of data into the memory (and it's much easier to develop and manage this kind of stuff when you're not very limited memory-wise).

Recently (after removing those x86 native dependencies), I changed the application compilation to "Any CPU", so now, on the production server, it runs as a 64-bit process. Starting when I did this change, the average memory consumption (according to the task manager) got to new levels: 3-4 **GB**, when there is no other change that may explain this change in behavior.

Here are some additional facts about the current state:

- According to the "#Bytes in all heaps" counter, the total amount of memory is about 600MB.
- When debugging the process with WinDbg+SOS, !dumpheap -stat showed that there are about 250-300MB free, but all the other object was much less than the total amount of memory the process used.
- According to the GC performance counters, there are Gen0 collections on regular basis. In fact, the "% Time in GC" counter indicates that 10-20% in average of the time spent on GC (which makes sense given the nature of the application - a lot of allocations of information and data structures that are in use for short time).
- I'm using Server GC in this app.
- There is no memory problem on the server. It uses about 50-60% of the available memory (64GB).

My questions:

- Why is a great difference between the memory allocated to the process (according to the task manager) and the actual size of the CLR heap (there is no un-managed code in the process that can explain this)?
- Why is the 64-bit process takes more memory compared to the same process running as 32-bit process? even when considering that pointers takes twice the size, there's a big difference.
- Can i do something to lower the memory consumption, or to have better understanding of the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You postponed dealing with that leak problem *far* too long, flipping the ignore-bit twice.  You can't flip it again.  You'll have to find the leak, it is an unmanaged one.  Bitmaps are the standard gobblers.

Comment: Something I observed is .NET 4 uses more than double the memory than .NET 2-3.5 in ASP.NET.

Comment: Private working set is not the memory used. It is the memory "used" (for some definition of that word) *that is also paged in*. Use the counter "private memory". Makes sense to me: Memory usage didn't fit into 2GB so you increased the available memory. Now don't be surprised if memory usage is above 2GB. In fact, the 300MB number should have been suspicious to you from the start. Why would a 2GB address space not fit 300MB of memory.

Comment: To make my previous comment actionable: Look at the private memory counter for both 32 bit and 64 bit. Memory usage will be within 2x. Now save some memory using application changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

1) You mentioned you're using Server GC mode. In server GC mode, CLR creates one heap for every CPU core on the machine, which is more efficient more multi-threaded processing in server processes, e.g. Asp.Net processes. Each heap has two segment: one for small objects, one for large objects. Each segment starts with 4 gb reserved memory. Basically server GC mode tries to use more memory on the system to trade for overall system performance.

2) Pointer is bigger on 64-bit, of course.

3) Foreground Gen2 GC becomes super expensive in server GC mode due to heap is much larger. So CLR tries super hard to reduce the number of foreground Gen2 GC, sometimes using background Gen2 GC.

4) Depending on usage, fragmentation can become a real issue. I've seen heaps with 98% fragmentation (98% heap is free blocks).

To really solve your problem, you need to get an ETW trace + a memory dump, and then use tools like PerfView for detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit process will naturally use 64-bit pointers, effectively doubling the memory usage of every reference. Certain platform-dependent variables such as IntPtr will also take up double the space.

The first and best thing you can do is to run a memory profiler to see where exactly the extra memory footprint is coming from. Anything else is speculative!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. As I said, I'm well aware to the difference in the pointer size. Even so, the total amount of memory got way bigger than the twice the size. In addition, I checked the allocated objects using WinDbg - the total size of all the object, free space included, was about 1/4 of the size of the memory (according to the task manager). I'm looking for explanation for this, if you have one - i'd be happy if you share. Thanks again.